# Multiple Hover Links in CSS

Tags: html, css

got a row of 4 social media buttons, they all hover when I move over them. However, I cannot get the tumblr pic to work. As it stands, on the preview, it goes twitter 'linkedin - linkedin - facebook

any help? Here's the CSS code I'm using

```
    .social a:link {
    float: center;
    background-image: url(../img/tumbler.png);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: 0 -30px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .3s ease;
       -moz-transition: background-position .3s ease;
         -o-transition: background-position .3s ease;
            transition: background-position .3s ease;
    margin-left: 2px;

}
.social a:link {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(../img/linkedin.png);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: 0 -30px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-position .3s ease;
    -o-transition: background-position .3s ease;
    transition: background-position .3s ease;
    margin-left: 2px;

}
.social a:first-child {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(../img/facebook.png);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: 0 -30px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-position .3s ease;
    -o-transition: background-position .3s ease;
    transition: background-position .3s ease;
    margin-left: 2px;

}
.social a:last-child {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(../img/twitter.png);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: 0 -30px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .3s ease;
       -moz-transition: background-position .3s ease;
         -o-transition: background-position .3s ease;
            transition: background-position .3s ease;

}
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you post your HTML and a fiddle?

Comment: Is it possible that "tumbler.png" should be "tumblr.png"? Or was that typo in the file name as well?

Comment: What do you expect `float:center` to do?

Comment: the float center was just an experiment - i forgot to change it back. its a typo, I've fixed that. but I still cant figure out how to sort this?

Comment: 'code'<div class="social six columns omega">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/iammarksummerton" target="new"></a>
                        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/iammarksummerton" target="new"></a>
                        <a href="http://iammarksummerton.tumblr.com/" target="new"></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/immarksummerton" target="new"></a>
                        
     </div> <!--Close Social Div-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the exact same CSS rule to do both Tumblr and linkedin. So `background-image: url(../img/linkedin.png)` is overriding `background-image: url(../img/tumbler.png)`. Give each of your social icons a separate class and style that.

eg:

```
<div class = "social">
    <a class = "twitter"></a>
    <a class = "linkedin"></a>
    <a class = "tumblr"></a>
    <a class = "facebook"></a>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.social a:link {
float: right;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background-position: 0 -30px;
-webkit-transition: background-position .3s ease;
-moz-transition: background-position .3s ease;
-o-transition: background-position .3s ease;
transition: background-position .3s ease;
margin-left: 2px;
}

.social .twitter{
 background-image: url(../img/twitter.png);
}

.social .linkedin{
background-image: url(../img/linkedin.png);
}

.social .tumblr{
background-image: url(../img/tumbler.png);
}

.social .facebook{
background-image: url(../img/facebook.png);
}
```

Also, check you've spelled "tumbler.png" correctly.